# GraphView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-graphview

I want to display a graph in a fragment, but I didn't found many information about how to use GraphView in general. Can someone please help me to display a simple graph?

I started with this: http://android-graphview.org/#doc_createsimplegraph    but don't get it working in a fragment.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was to create a `fragment_graph.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dip"
    android:id="@+id/graph1"
    android:background="#102f65" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and add the relevant code in the Fragment class:

```
public class GraphFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                           ViewGroup container, 
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);

    // add the data here if necessary
    // ...

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.graph1);
    layout.addView(graphView);

    return view;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Then you can use the fragment "as is".

Most credit actually goes to [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

define a empty LinearLayout with fixed width and height in your layout.xml file and then add the graphview view to it.

Layout

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="250dip"
                        android:id="@+id/graph1" />
```

Java

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
layout.addView(graphView);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! And instead of   "this"    for the context I simple have to use getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:
You cannot use it in connection with ScrollViews. If a ScrollView is wrapping your LinearLayout the lib doesn't show anything.